# How to have my ListView catch onLongClick() (not onItemLongClick)

Tags: android, listview, long-click

I have a `ListView` that is refreshed at a high rate (3 times per second).

I need to catch a long press on such a `ListView` (as well as on the parent layout); the `ListView` has it's height set to `wrap_content`.

I can catch the long click on the parent layout, but I wish the long click on any item to be handled by the parent layout.

`OnItemLongClick` does not work well due to the high refresh rate, I have tried the `onLongClickListener` to the `ListView` but the the long click is not fired.

The rows are set as non-clickable, not-focusable as well as all the items contained in the row.

The question is how to handle a long click anywhere in the `ListView` if the position / item does not matter?

Comment: Why do you need to refresh this often? Maybe there's a better way to go about this.

Comment: Not really, the data are coming trough Bluetooth at high rate and the user needs to see the evolution. Maybe I have to write my layout container and work with onInterceptTouchEvent ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue (with clicks on `ImageButton`s) when I was updating progress of my downloads in a `ListView`.

The solution was to update the individual rows instead of calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` (as what I understand is it interferes with your click/touch listeners). So to do this I problem was to find the row accurately. I need two things for this:

1. mapping of *URL strings to my `Transfer` objects* (`mPathToTransfers`),
2. *list of URLs* (`mPathKeys`).

Here's some code from my adapter:

```java
protected LinkedHashMap<String, BaseTransfer> mPathToTransfers;
protected List<String> mPathKeys;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    mPathKeys = new ArrayList<String>(mPathToTransfers.keySet());
    return mPathToTransfers.size();
}

@Override
public BaseTransfer getItem(int position) {
    return mPathToTransfers.get(mPathKeys.get(position));
}

/**
 * Update transfer (download) progress in ListView's specific row
*/
public void setItemTransferredSize(String path, long transferredSize, ListView lv) {
    if (mPathToTransfers.containsKey(path)) {
        BaseTransfer dItem = (BaseTransfer) mPathToTransfers.get(path);
        dItem.setTransferredSize(transferredSize);

        Holder holder = getViewHolderForTransfer(path, lv);
        if (holder != null)
            setTransferProgressUpdate(holder, dItem);
    }
}

/**
 * Use to get the View Holder of the row of the transfer
 *
 * @param path
 * @param lv
 * @return {@linkplain Holder} for row, if it is visible, null otherwise
 */
private Holder getViewHolderForTransfer(String path, ListView lv) {
    int rowIndex = mPathKeys.indexOf(path);
    if (lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() <= rowIndex && lv.getLastVisiblePosition() >= rowIndex)
        return (Holder) lv.getChildAt(rowIndex - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()).getTag();
    else
        return null;
}
```

If you have ambiguities, ask in comments below (or in your question's comments). :)

Comment: In my app, the maximum number of row I can get is 15, minimum is 0. True that I could use a simple layout with elements for possible rows. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I don't think all 15 will be visible at one time, not on a small 3.2" device at least. I have tested this method and it works fine for me with 14 or 15 downloads (I was scrolling and the progress was updated fine). But if you're looking for a simpler solution, you may have to sacrifice on the generic behaviour my solution.

Comment: @francky when you do find a solution, post it as an answer for future reference for yourself and for others.